# Data not getting saved properly in excel file from stream writer

Tags: c#

i am trying to write the date format data into an  stream writer from  where  again am  writing into an excel file

here i am changing the  date  format like  this
  dd-MM-yyyy

```
StreamWriter strmWriteText= new
StreamWriter(); DateTime ldtPubmonth;
lstrmWriteText.Write(dsPubmonth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

but  when ever data  gets  saved in the excel  file  the  format is    getting changed  like this.

1/5/2010

actaully  it  should be like this  01-05-2010

is there  any thing that i am going wrong  like  saving the data.

when   i check the value in command  window ?dsPubmonth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
 it  shows   the value     01-05-2010

i am using VS 2003, .net 1.1

thanks

Comment: You try to read it using Excel? Because if you do, Excel will automatically take the default datetime format for displaying dates when it recognizes it.

Comment: Both riffnl and LaGrandMere are right. The issue is generated by the cell format from excel and not by your code. Changing that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should maybe edit the Column format ?

```
Excel.Range rg = (Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Cells[1,1];
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

If it's just for a Cell, don't use EntireColumn.

Comment: i have the data type as string StrDateNew=lStrDate.ToString(); here when i try to write this string into excel file it converts to datetime format  1/5/2010  why is  this happening  before  writing into excel  file the  data is in this format.